# How to check for post posted by same post_author in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i have this code in my view (show.html.erb) to check and display posts that were posted by the same author:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<!-- Check for same post author -->
<p><%= @post.title %></p>
<!-- End check -->
<% end %>
```

And here's my controller:

```
def show
@posts = Posts.all.order("created_at desc")
end
```

I tried `@sameauthor = Posts.where(post_author: params[:post_author]).order("created_at desc")`

Updated.

```
private
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :post_author)
    end
end
```

Comment: do you want to display all contents or just posts specific that created by post_author

Comment: only posts created by that post_author

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is:

```
def show
  @posts_by_same_author = Post.where('post_author = ?', @post.post_author).order("created_at desc")
end
```

It'll give you posts which is written by the current post (`@post`) author. Then iterate through this instance variable in view:

```
<% @posts_by_same_author.each do |post| %>
  <p><%= post.title %></p>
  <p><%= post.post_author %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You could possibly even shorten this to `@post.post_author.posts`, assuming the ActiveRecord associations are set correctly.